# Snowflake SQLAlchemy 'supports_statement_cache' warning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-connector

I'm querying data from Snowflake using SQLAlchemy and keep getting this warning:

SAWarning: Dialect snowflake:snowflake will not make use of SQL compilation caching as it does not set the 'supports_statement_cache' attribute to `True`.  This can have significant performance implications including some performance degradations in comparison to prior SQLAlchemy versions.  Dialect maintainers should seek to set this attribute to True after appropriate development and testing for SQLAlchemy 1.4 caching support.   Alternatively, this attribute may be set to False which will disable this warning. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/cprf)

I have some understanding of why the warning appears based on the link above, but I don't understand what steps I should take to avoid the 'significant performance implications'.

versions:

snowflake-connector-python==2.7.1

snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.3

SQLAlchemy==1.4.32

connection string:

```
 from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

def snowflake_connection(cred, params):

```
"""Connect to snowflake using connection params."""

logger.info("Connecting to snowflake...")

try:
    # connect to snowflake
    engine = create_engine(URL(
        user = cred['UN'],
        role = cred['ROLE'],
        password = cred['PWD'],
        account = params['account'],
        warehouse = params['warehouse']))

    conn = engine.connect()

    logger.info("...Connected to Snowflake.")
    return conn, engine

except Exception:
    logger.error("Failed to connect to Snowflake.", exc_info=True)
    conn.close()
    engine.dispose()
    sys.exit()
```

Question:

1. What kind of performance issues will this cause?
2. How can I address this warning?

Comment: There's not much you can do to address it, until the snowflake connector devs address it - see [this issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/265).

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs this for vertica:

```
from sqla_vertica_python.vertica_python import VerticaDialect
VerticaDialect.supports_statement_cache = True
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me. I added these lines after `import sqlalchemy as sa` and that managed to set the bit and eliminate the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to disable the warning with:

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy.snowdialect import SnowflakeDialect
SnowflakeDialect.supports_statement_cache = False
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need this for HANA:

```
from sqlalchemy_hana.dialect import HANAHDBCLIDialect
HANAHDBCLIDialect.supports_statement_cache = False
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).